# Spark reads double sized data

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark cluster in my private network, and I have a job containing only one line of code:

`spark.read.parquet('/path/to/data').count()`

I tried to run the job with same data on a EMR Spark cluster and my private Spark cluster, both with the same parameters:

`spark-submit --driver-memory 1G --driver-cores 1 --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 8G --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false dummy_job.py`

On the spark monitoring web page, I saw that EMR read only 3GiB data while my private cluster read 6.1GiB data

Both Spark clusters prunes reading size a lot, but EMR reads much less data, this may indicates that our gzidc Spark cluster has a incorrect configuration related parquet I/O.

Any ideas? Thanks

[image]